Finding any property containing a substring in Neo4j
I have a Neo4j database and I want to find any properties, in any nodes, that have a string value ending in ".0".
So: for all string properties in the database, regardless of the labels, I want to find the ones that contain at least one value ending in ".0". The desired return value is a list of property names.
Is it possible to do this with a Cypher query?

Something to get you started:
match (s)
with s, properties(s) as propMap
return
elementId(s) as node,
[
x in keys(propMap) where propMap[x] is ::STRING and propMap[x] ends with ".0" |
{key: x, value: propMap[x]}
] as hit
limit 1

This returns the distinct names of properties whose value (in any node) ends in '.0':
MATCH (n)
UNWIND KEYS(n) AS propName
WITH propName
WHERE n[propName] ENDS WITH '.0'
RETURN DISTINCT propName

The time complexity is O(N), where N is the number of nodes.
This query only tests properties that actually exist in each node (instead of testing each node for all properties that exist in any node or relationship).

plus one, at least someone read the question correctly :roll-eye"

You can use the following Cypher query. Note that it is very inefficient and this query is recommended ONLY on small size databases.
CALL db.propertyKeys() YIELD propertyKey
MATCH (n) WHERE n[propertyKey] ENDS WITH '.0'
RETURN n

If you want to filter upfront to do a MATCH with only propertyKeys of type STRING, you can use the following query
CALL db.schema.nodeTypeProperties()
YIELD propertyName, propertyTypes
WHERE "String" IN propertyTypes
WITH propertyName AS propertyKey
MATCH (n) WHERE n[propertyKey] ENDS WITH '.0'
RETURN n

